# Return Elements in the array that start with a specific letter e.g D

Tags: arrays, ruby, methods, hash

I am having issue with my code below. I am new to ruby. I want to return names that only start with the letter D but it just returns all the names. When I try the .start_with? method it returns an error message "undefined method .start_with?". Any help would be amazing, thank you

```
students = [
  {name: "Dr. Hannibal Lecter", cohort: :november},
  {name: "Darth Vader", cohort: :november},
  {name: "Nurse Ratched", cohort: :november},
  {name: "Michael Corleone", cohort: :november},
  {name: "Alex DeLarge", cohort: :november},
  {name: "The Wicked Witch of the West", cohort: :november},
  {name: "Terminator", cohort: :november},
  {name: "Freddy Krueger", cohort: :november},
  {name: "The Joker", cohort: :november},
  {name: "Joffrey Baratheon", cohort: :november},
  {name: "Norman Bates", cohort: :november}
]

students.each{ |x| puts x if x[0] == 'D' }
```

Answer (score 3):

You are sending a message to a Hash for it to respond when it `start_with?` a "D". But a Hash does not have a `start_with?` method - so it gives you the error message.

You are looking for a specific key (:name)  in a hash, so you'll have to specify which key:

```
   students.each{ |x| puts x if x[:name].start_with? 'D' }
```

Answer (score 1):

### Your Block Variable is an Array, Not a Hash

In your existing code, you are assigning each element of the array to *x*, but the variable your comparing is a [Hash](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Hash.html) rather than an [Array](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Array.html). What you actually want to do is iterate through the Hash objects in your Array, and then check each [String](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/String.html) assigned to the *:name* key for that Hash rather than the value of a non-existent key of `0`. For example, using Ruby 3.1.1 with the [Array#select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Array.html#method-i-select) method:

```rb
students.select { |hash| hash[:name].start_with? 'D' }
#=> 
[{:name=>"Dr. Hannibal Lecter", :cohort=>:november},                            
 {:name=>"Darth Vader", :cohort=>:november}]
```

However, note that the results will return:

1. The whole Hash that matches your [Array#select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Array.html#method-i-select) statement.
2. Won't differentiate between names and titles. It's just looking and the value of the key for the first letter, so you might need additional code to handle titles, suffixes like `Jr.` or `Sr.`, and so forth if you're trying to properly alphabetize a list of names.

That may not matter for your immediate purposes, but these caveats are worth pointing out for future reference.

### Extract Just the Names

If you just want the name, and not the whole Hash, then you can use Array#map to return just the value from the matching Hash key when a match is found, and chain it to [Array#compact](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Array.html#method-i-compact) which will remove any `nil` values in the Array returned by the [Array#map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Array.html#method-i-map) method. For example:

```rb
students.map do |hash|
  hash[:name] if hash[:name].start_with? 'D'
end.compact
#=> ["Dr. Hannibal Lecter", "Darth Vader"]
```

Comment: The last snippet can be written as `students.filter_map{ |hash| hash[:name] if hash[:name].start_with? 'D' }`

Comment: @steenslag Thanks for suggesting [Enumerable#filter_map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-filter_map). I was just trying to make the answer clear for the OP without having to refer to Enumerable, or use syntax features not present in older Rubies. Personally, I'd have done `students.filter_map { $& if _1[:name] =~ /^D.*/ }` if I really wanted something shorter and more concise (if not necessarily faster).  The String method is about twice as fast as the Regexp matching, but it fits my brain better. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'select' method, this go through all the array and extract only the ones that meet the conditions you place.
Also you can use regex, it is really helpful when you are working with strings.
Here is a website where you can practice regex: https://rubular.com
This is my code

```
puts students.select { |hash| hash[:name].match?(/^D/) }
```

I hope it can be helpful.